# Changing profile picture privately

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

How do I change my profile picture back to an already existing one without it appearing on other's timeline or it being in everyone's newsfeed?

Answer (score 1):

You will see an option called Update Profile Picture. If you do not want to show this update publicly or you want to change Facebook profile picture without notifying friends, you need to make this update “Private”. For that, click the globe sign visible next to the date/time and select Only me. That's all!